# How to get google key?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to use Google Maps on my activity. For that I have to register my project with a key.

I got following MD5 FingerPrint:

```
E2:BC:9A:08:73:37:BD:80:2E:EA:5D:84:C6:D1:2B:0C
```

Now I am not able to get google key.Please help me in finding key.

Comment: We have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: I want to use google map on my activity.For that I have to register my project with a key.that key i want to get.

Comment: Se [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are talking about maps-api-signup key than you can paste your MD5 Fingerprint to below link and get your KEY from there.

[The Google Maps API KEY](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key)

**EDITED:**

```
INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
```

you are getting  this problem because you forgot to add below line inside menifest:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> between <application> </application>
```

> Make sure you have your  element in your manifest, that
>   **your project is set up to target API level 3 (android create project
>   -t 3 ...), and that the AVD you are testing with is also set for API level 3 (or you are testing on an actual device with Google Maps on in it.**

Hope it will help out.

Comment: I put key.but while running my program my project,it's showing following error:  Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Comment: @kumar: i have edited my answer. you can try it out.

Comment: I put it already!but still it is showing same error.

Comment: That's the deprecated API

Comment: @Kumar: look at my improved answer.

Comment: @ScottStanchfield: Thnks for your correction. Now i have updated my link for it. thnks.

Comment: @all:thanks everyone..Now I can see google map on my avd.

Comment: One more question! what are debug and releasing key? how and when we'll implement these keys?

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking to get the google maps api key? If so, see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start